# Differential operator computation

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I need to show that if

$\omega=xydx+3dy-yzdz$

$\nu=xdx-yz^2dy+2xdz$

then $d(\omega\land\nu)=(d\omega)\land\nu-\omega\land(d\nu)$

I really do not understand how this differential operators work. I would be thankful of someone helped me with this

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean \nu=xdx-yz^2dy+2xdz instead?

Comment: @ililil yes. I edited it. thanks

Comment: I'd say go back to the definition. $d_{a}f = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(a)dx_{i}}$

Comment: @krirkrirk i can't still do it

Comment: @Marion Crane: The objects you deal with are differential-forms.
One very often find them behind the integral-symbol.
First you should build the wedge-product of them, second you should calculate the exterior derivative for this product.
That's the Cartan-Derivative. Very useful objects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the left hand side:

$\omega\land\nu=-xy^2z^2dx\land dy + 2x^2y dx \land dz + 3x dy \land dx + 6x dy \land dz - xyz dz \land dx + y^2z^3 dz \land dy $

$ =-xy^2z^2dx\land dy + 2x^2y dx \land dz - 3x dx \land dy + 6x dy \land dz + xyz dx \land dz - y^2z^3 dy \land dz $

$ =(-xy^2z^2-3x)dx\land dy + (2x^2y+ xyz) dx \land dz + (6x- y^2z^3) dy \land dz $

$d(\omega\land\nu)=-2xy^2z dz \land dx \land dy + (2x^2+ xz) dy \land dx \land dz + 6 dx \land dy \land dz $

$ = (-2x^2 -2xy^2z -xz +6) dx \land dy \land dz $

On the right hand side:

$d\omega = x dy \land dx - z dy \land dz $

$d\nu = - 2yz dz \land dy + 2 dx \land dz $

$d\omega \land \nu = -2x^2 dx \land dy \land dx - xz dy \land dz \land dx $

$\omega \land d\nu = 2xy^2z dx \land dy \land dz + 6 dy \land dx \land dz $

$d\omega \land \nu - \omega \land d\nu = (-2xy^2z-2x^2) dx \land dy \land dz + (-6+xz) dy \land dx \land dz $

$ = (-2x^2 -2xy^2z -xz +6) dx \land dy \land dz $